# Как узнать координаты картинки на странице по клику?

Tags: javascript

У меня в php скрипте генерируется с помощью `echo` javascript, а также множество картинок с помощью тега `img`. У каждой картинки есть свой ID.

Мне нужно в джаваскрипте по ID получить координаты картинки, сгенерированной из php. Как мне это сделать?

Так у меня генерируются картинки в php:

```
    foreach($files as $str){
    echo '<tr>';
echo "<td><tr><img onclick='javascript:imgclick($ii)' id = '$ii' src='http://clroyale.ru/wp-content/plugins/royale/cards/$str'></img></tr></td>";
echo '</tr>';
    $ii = $ii + 1;
}
```

Comment: Под координатами вы подразумеваете путь к картинке? Если да, то почему бы не передавать его вместо ID картинки, раз манипулировать вы будете им?

Comment: Нет, координаты это место расположения картинки на веб странице.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Обновлено**.

Координаты относительно документа, не окна!

Версия 1, кроссбраузерная.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 2000px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function imgclick(id) {
      var elem = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[id];

      function getCoords(elem) {
        // (1)
        var box = elem.getBoundingClientRect();

        var body = document.body;
        var docEl = document.documentElement;

        // (2)
        var scrollTop = window.pageYOffset || docEl.scrollTop || body.scrollTop;
        var scrollLeft = window.pageXOffset || docEl.scrollLeft || body.scrollLeft;

        // (3)
        var clientTop = docEl.clientTop || body.clientTop || 0;
        var clientLeft = docEl.clientLeft || body.clientLeft || 0;

        // (4)
        var top = box.top + scrollTop - clientTop;
        var left = box.left + scrollLeft - clientLeft;

        return {
          top: top,
          left: left
        };
      }

      console.log(getCoords(elem));

      var d = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(d);

      d.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(getCoords(elem));
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://wiseparents.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/durachitsya.png" alt="" onclick="imgclick(0)">

</body>

</html>
```

Версия 2: более простая. Была ошибочка, `coor.top` в хроме пашет, `coor.y` не пашет.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>titile</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
    body,
    html {
      height: 2000px;
    }
  </style>
  <script>
    function imgclick(id) {
      var coor = document.getElementsByTagName('img')[id].getBoundingClientRect();

      var d = document.createElement('div');
      document.body.appendChild(d);

      console.log(coor.y);

      d.innerHTML = 'y: ' + (coor.top + pageYOffset) + ', x: ' + (coor.left + pageXOffset) + ', height: ' + coor.height + ', width: ' + coor.width;
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <img src="http://wiseparents.ru/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/durachitsya.png" alt="" onclick="imgclick(0)">

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Результат `y: NaN, x: NaN, height: 370, width: 350` в Яндекс.Браузере.

Comment: @VenZell да и в хроме тоже. (c) Chromium

Comment: @ven Ладно, дадно, стибрил.

Comment: @ВасилийБарбашев ладно, обновил.

Comment: Спасибо огромное, работает замечательно

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById("").getBoundingClientRect();
alert(x.top);
alert(x.left);
```